# Make the tag [gui-thread] a synonym for [ui-thread]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The tags [gui-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gui-thread) (12) and [ui-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ui-thread) (269) are basically the same. Either one could be a synonym for the other, so this is just my personal suggestion:

<strike><sub>Despite the number of questions in both tags, which would suggest just the opposite, I recommend that [ui-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ui-thread) (269) become a synonym for [gui-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gui-thread) (12).</sub></strike>

<sub>Rationale: Not all user interfaces (UIs) necessarily have a dedicated thread — console applications come to mind —, but graphical user interface (GUIs) frameworks often do. When people say "UI thread", they are usually talking about it in the context of a GUI; therefore "UI thread" seems the less accurate term.</sub>

I had a change of mind: Perhaps it makes more sense to take a down-to-earth stance, and choose as the main tag that which is simpler, and more commonly used anyway (that is, [ui-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ui-thread)) and make [gui-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gui-thread) the synonym.

Comment: 'UI thread' is exactly what it is commonly called in WPF and Silverlight. So I suggest you don't make it the synonym. Is there a possibility that 'gui-thread' is used in the same way for other tech stacks, so shouldn't be synonymised either?

Comment: @slugster: It's my belief that the two terms are perfectly synonymous. After all, how many user interfaces (UIs) do you know today that are *not* graphical (GUIs)? Perhaps next to none. I had a change of mind and am supporting your proposition: [ui-thread] would be a fine choice as the main tag.

Comment: I'm more in favour of your updated option. I've just taken a pass through the `gui-thread` list and retagged at least half of them - it seemed in those cases it was a coin toss which term the author selected. At this moment there is only two questions left, if they get retagged the tag will be automatically culled so a synonym won't be required (although it could still be done).

Comment: @slugster: It seems that at least Qt leans towards "GUI thread"; and perhaps the Windows' native API. When I last checked, there were again not 2, but 7 questions tagged `[gui-thread]`. I got it back down, but for the remaining 2 questions, retagging would seem improper IMO. So I still think a synonym would be a good idea.

Comment: Looks like the last two questions were re-tagged or deleted, as the [gui-thread] tag is gone